# Program will not run completely through code (no errors) Python 2.7.15

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am very new to programming (as in a few weeks ago - sorry in advance for any ignorant coding!) but I am trying to run a function defined and user input code that finds the minimum of 3 integers. It will properly ask for the 3 integers, but then returns nothing after that even though I have the minimum function written. 
[My code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4dQ3.png)

Comment: Please add your code to the question rather than just a picture of your code

Comment: What do you expect the code to do? You don't do anything with the values you return. Did you perhaps want to print in your `get_minimum` function instead of returning?

Comment: okay thanks! @G.Anderson

Comment: yes thank you! @DavidG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You coded your program a bit awkwardly. However, that aside, you can get your method to output by using the `print` statement as opposed to the `return`.

Otherwise, when you return something from a function you need to assign what is returned to some variable(s).

For example:

```
def getter():
     return "Hello, world" 

r = getter()

print r
```

Output:

```
Hello, world
```

So, `return "Hello, world"` will assign `"Hello, world"` to `r`. However, nothing will be shown in your terminal. In order for it to be shown in your terminal, you would have to use the `print` statement.

And just as a side note, it is best to paste your code in as opposed to attaching pictures.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need globals since you are also *returning* the entered values. But you must save them on returning from `get_integers`. After that, you can simply use the `min` function to get the minimum value in a list:

```
def get_integers():
    N1 = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
    N2 = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
    N3 = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
    return N1,N2,N3

def get_minimum(*values):
    print ("The minimum is {:d}".format(min(list(values))))

a,b,c = get_integers()
get_minimum(a,b,c)
```